# Editing tab-delimited .txt files from Excel in vim

Tags: microsoft-excel, unix, vim, text-editors, unicode

When I save a simple spreadsheet in Excel 15.41 (on Mac) as tab-delimited .txt and open it using `vim <filename>`, I see characters for carriage returns as `^M`, but everything is on one line. There is one `$` character shown at the end of the single line when I use `:set list`:

```
1^I2^I3^I4^M1^I2^I3^I4^M1^I2^I3^I4$
```

Because `fileformat=unix` for this file, I expected to see no carriage return characters. Does anyone know why I'm seeing the opposite? I am also unsure of why all lines are read as one following this procedure.

When I save the same spreadsheet as UTF-16 unicode .txt and open it using vim, `fileformat=dos`. `:set list` properly shows line ending characters, but there are no carriage return characters. My understanding was that DOS files should also contain a carriage return at line endings.

```
1^I2^I3^I4$     
1^I2^I3^I4$     
1^I2^I3^I4$
```

There is a lot of information out there about line endings, but I could not find a direct answer to explain these observations. Any help or direction to clarifying resources would be much appreciated.

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, Vim apparently doesn't properly detect the line endings. The sole use of CR (`^M`) is the (old) Mac-style. You can add `mac` to the `'fileformats'` option, or explicitly specify the format when opening:

```
:edit ++ff=mac FILE.txt
```